# Apache2 deny access to folder but not to alias

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2, httpd.conf

I have a root directory like:

```
- /var/www/html/
    - index.html
    - default_directory/
        - index.html
```

I have many aliases that points on the default_directory, I need this because I have a single same website for many pages that serve different content based on url.

Can I deny access to that folder using `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess` but allowing aliases to access to it?

Comment: So the only thing you want to prevent, is access via `http://main-domain.com/default_directory/`, but access via any of the alias domains should be allowed? (And by deny access, you mean deny to serve _any_ resource inside that folder, and not _just_ prevent an automatic directory listing when just the directory gets requested, yes?) I’d probably use mod_rewrite for that, RewriteCond that checks on the host name, and a RewriteRule that simply uses the `F` flag to answer with 403 Forbidden then.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for response. Yes I want to deny access to the whole folder but allow to aliases pointing to that folder. Could you provide me an example please?

Comment: Please do some research yourself first, if any of the details are unclear. Once you show us something that you tried, we can discuss that.

Comment: My aliases are `/alias1 /var/www/html/default-directory/` and `/alias2 /var/www/html/default-directory/`
I tried using 
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /default-directory/ - [F] `

but it denies access to aliases too

Comment: You only want to redirect when this was requested via a specific host name, that’s why I said _“RewriteCond that checks on the host name.”_ Try and add `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=main-domain.com` before the rule.

Comment: Nie, hostname is always my domain, I just want to hide and deny access to that folder but aliases created in `httpd.conf` must be allowed. I tried uwind the `RewriteRule` but it blocks aliases too

Comment: _“hostname is always my domain”_ - ah. News to me. (I did explicitly ask what the exactly situation was in the first comment …) I’m guessing resolving the aliases means the _internal_ URL will be `/default-directory/` at some point, and that’s what the RewriteRule is picking up on then at that point. Try checking `%{REQUEST_URI}` in a RewriteCond then, that should always be the originally requested URL. Follow it by a RewriteRule that matches anything, and set the `F` flag.

Comment: Maybe I explained it bad, sorry. I'll give a try
Thank you